# Can exponential functions have "complex" solutions?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Do exponential functions, take $e^x$, have imaginary solutions just as a function like $\sqrt x$ has complex solutions? I know $e^{i\pi} = -1$ but I'm not sure how this works or relates.

Comment: $$e^{\ln\left(\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\right)+i\arctan\frac cb}=b+ic$$

Comment: Functions don't have solutions. Equations have solutions, problems have solutions, but functions don't have solutions. So, what do you actually want to know?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was thinking about the function y=e^x (any base, it doesn't matter)  and how obviously no real value of x will ever make y a negative number. But is there some sort of z such that y in y=e^z can be negative? Analogous to how no real value of x can produce a negative number for y in y=x^2.

Comment: Yes, there is such a $z$, and you've written it: $e^{i\pi}=-1$. More generally, if $a$ is real, then $e^{a+i\pi}$ is the negative number $-e^a$. But that doesn't mean that the function $e^x$ has imaginary *solutions*; it means the *equation* $e^x=w$ has complex solutions, for negative real values of $w$.

Comment: Anyway, are you happy with the answer José Carlos Santos posted a couple of months ago? or is there something still not clear to you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think its all good now. I was just confused at the time.

Answer (score 1):

If $w\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, you can write it as $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, with $r>0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb R$. Then$$e^{\log r+\theta i}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=w.$$